# How to trigger the css style as we typing the onChange in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

is there a way to change the style of input width as we type in React?

My initial `width` of my input is `1ch`. I want to make it increase/decrease when the character growing/shrinking while I'm typing/focus, so the % will stay at the end.

my code onChanges for the style is this line

```
e.target.style.width = e.target.value.length + 'ch'
```

But seems didn't work at all. How to trigger this input size width?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the style of input width as we type in React like this example component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const InputComponent = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
        style={{ width: `${inputValue.length}ch` }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputComponent;
```